# Access AppData folder in json settings file in c#

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, serilog

I am using serilog and configuring the sink using settings.json. There is a part where it asks for the location to which the files will be stored locally. The process running the application has to have enough permissions to access this folder and create, delete files.

I want to avoid hard coding and use the preferred way of using [Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) enum.

It is possible to do it somehow?

Here is what I have currently. It works but not a fool proof solution.

```
"bufferBaseFilename": "C:\\Logs\\FileBuffer"
```

Comment: is it possible when application start simpally put the string  value of Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData in setting using  file read write.